# Mock gps location route in web browser

Tags: web, geolocation, mocking, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

In order to test a html app I need to mock routes. So far I have been able to simulate one position with the chrome developers tools using the override in the settings. How ever I need to simulate a track, not just a solo point.

Is there a way to mock a track in web?

Searching I saw that in Android is possible using a location mocking service, I need that functionality but in web.

So far I have been testing with position that I can create on the fly clicking in a map (the app displays a map), but I would like to automate that.

Any plugin or feature I have missed in the dev tools?

Update: I have recently found that changing the override value in chrome dev tools changes instantly the value read ( I don't know how I has trying before ....). This is a temporary solution but it is tedious to test routes with many points.

Comment: This might be the addon? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/geo-devtool/

Comment: I tried the add-on, how ever it doesn't seems to work, there is also a comment con the add-on stating that it doesn't work dated on November 2013. I have tried it in a FF26 on Win and in FF27 on Ubuntu, neither worked. But an add-on like that would work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the Fiddler HTTP  debugger has a proxy server and write custom rules for it to return geolocation data per your requirements. (I have not tested this approach myself).

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler